# XslCompiledTransform compilation error

Tags: c#, xslt, xslcompiledtransform

I have this xslt stylesheet, in file Empty.xslt:

`<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:nrki="http://www.essox.cz/xslt/nrki" xmlns:date="http://www.essox.cz/xslt/date" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" extension-element-prefixes="nrki date">
        <xsl:import href="C:\Users\pparik.ESSOX\Desktop\Xslt\General.xslt" />
        <xsl:import href="C:\Users\pparik.ESSOX\Desktop\Xslt\Nrki\General.xslt" />
        <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />
        <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
            <xsl:if test="nrki:IsInLastDays('15042011', 6)">
                je
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>`

When I select menu item (in Visual studio) XML / Show XSLT Output, I get correct results.
But when I try to do the same using code (XslCompiledTransform), I get compilation error exception.

```
string output = string.Empty;
XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform(true);
XsltSettings sett = new XsltSettings(true, true);
transform.Load(new XmlTextReader(@"C:\Users\pparik.ESSOX\Documents\Essox\Zdrojové kódy\SES\Visual studio\SesSolution\TestXslt\Xslt sablony\Empty.xslt"), sett, null);
StringWriter sr = new StringWriter();
transform.Transform(this.EvaluationInput.CreateNavigator(), null, sr);
output = sr.ToString();
```

Any idea why? Thanks a lot,
Petr

Comment: What exactly does the error say?

Comment: Also, without the supporting (imported) xslts, the answer may be ambiguous. Hard coding the absolute paths like that isn't really a great idea, to be honest.

Comment: You shouldn't get normal results in both cases, as you are referencing the extension function `nrki:IsInLastDays()`, but no extension object is defined in the code. In case you do define these extension functions, then you need to provide all the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comment on the `XmlResolver` argument where you are passing in `null`:

> If this is null, external resources are not resolved.

Yet `C:\Users\pparik.ESSOX\Desktop\Xslt\General.xslt` ***is*** an external resource. Try passing in a `new XmlUrlResolver()` instead of `null`.

Also, you are over-complicating the load by using `XmlTextReader` - this is easier:

```
transform.Load(path, sett, new XmlUrlResolver());
```

For info, you can supply your own custom resolvers if you like - for example, I wrote one that re-mapped relative paths to contents from a resx, so the files could be edited normally in the IDE but then included as embedded resources (but still resolve their siblings correctly).